# Having issues with dropdown boxes displaying information in a fillable PDF based on previous selection - JS

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am quite new to JS, and I am having a bit of trouble getting multiple dropdowns in a PDF to display the same information, based on another dropdown choice.

So lets say I have 5 dropdown menu's in my PDF (1 through 5). Dropdown 1 will populate Dropdown 2. Based on the selection of Dropdown 2, dropdown menu's 3 thru 5 should display the same information.

Example:

Dropdown 2 has 3 choices (A,B,C). If choice A is selected, dropdowns 3-5 should each display 1,2,3. If B is selected, each should display 4,5,6. If C is selected, each should display 7,8,9.

All I can ever get to work is dropdown 3. The others just show up as blank.

Code as follows:

```
var dropdown = this.getField("Dropdown2");
var crewtype = 0;
for (i=0; i<dropdown.numItems; i++) {
    if(dropdown.getItemAt(i, false) == event.value) {
        crewtype = dropdown.getItemAt(i, true);
    }
}

switch (crewtype) {
    case "A": this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(
            ["1", "2", "3"]);
        break;
    case "A": this.getField("Dropdown4").setItems(
            ["1", "2", "3"]);
        break;
    case "A": this.getField("Dropdown5").setItems(
            ["1", "2", "3"]);
        break;
    case "B": this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(
            ["4", "5", "6"]);
        break;
    case "B": this.getField("Dropdown4").setItems(
            ["4", "5", "6"]);
        break;
    case "B": this.getField("Dropdown5").setItems(
            ["4", "5", "6"]);
        break;
    case "C": this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(
            ["7", "8", "9"]);
        break;
    case "C": this.getField("Dropdown4").setItems(
            ["7", "8", "9"]);
        break;
    case "C": this.getField("Dropdown5").setItems(
            ["7", "8", "9"]);
        break;
    default: this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(
            ["Select Code:"]);
        break;
}
```

Sorry for the messy code, I am about as green with code as green can get.

How do I get dropdowns 4 & 5 to show the same info as dropdown 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch case breaks after each case. You should probably club it like:

```
 switch (crewtype) {
  case "A":
    this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(["1", "2", "3"]);
    this.getField("Dropdown4").setItems(["1", "2", "3"]);
    this.getField("Dropdown5").setItems(["1", "2", "3"]);
    break;
  case "B":
    this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(["4", "5", "6"]);
    this.getField("Dropdown4").setItems(["4", "5", "6"]);
    this.getField("Dropdown5").setItems(["4", "5", "6"]);
    break;
  case "C":
    this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(["7", "8", "9"]);
    this.getField("Dropdown4").setItems(["7", "8", "9"]);
    this.getField("Dropdown5").setItems(["7", "8", "9"]);
    break;
  default:
    this.getField("Dropdown3").setItems(["Select Code:"]);
    break;
}
```

Comment: That seemed to have worked.  I am going to apply it in my non-test environment and see how that goes!

Comment: Glad it helped!